# How to install VSCode on Raspberry Pi

Tags: visual-studio-code, raspberry-pi

I am trying to install vscode onto my raspberry pi.

I have tried going to the vscode website to download it, but when I try to install it I get the error "failed to install file". I am not sure what to do.

Comment: https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-visual-studio-code/

Answer (score 1):

It's simply not supported at this time. The linux versions made available on the official download page are for Linux PCs, not Raspberry Pis. The error you get belies this incompatibility. The only means of getting Code on a Pi is via unofficial ports, as outlined in the link provided by the other answerer.

Answer (score 0):

Not officially supported, but you can install this unofficial build, open up a terminal on the Pi:

```
sudo su
. <( wget -O - https://code.headmelted.com/installers/apt.sh )
```

More information [here](https://code.headmelted.com/)

If it fails to install (authentication issues), you can force it with:

```
sudo apt install code-oss libnspr4 libnss3 libsecret-1-0 libsecret-common libxkbfile1 --allow-unauthenticated
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a distro for Raspberry Pi, Jetson Nano and similar ARM A Linux devices.

```
wget https://packagecloud.io/headmelted/codebuilds/gpgkey -O - | sudo apt-key add -

curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/headmelted/codebuilds/master/docs/installers/apt.sh | sudo bash
```

If you want to type `code` instead of `code-oss`, then:

```
cd /usr/bin && sudo ln -s code-oss code
```